# CloudSQL for Postgres S3 extension

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

In AWS RDS for Postgres, there is an extension called AWS_S3 that provides functions within Postgres that allow me to import data directly from a bucket into a table and export data from a table directly into a bucket.

Example:

```
SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
   'test_gzip', '', '(csv format)',
   'myS3Bucket', 'test-data.gz', 'us-east-2'
);
```

There's nothing similar in CloudSQL for Postgres. Has anyone had this type of problem? How can I solve it?